# Django: How to also migrate the name of a Primary Key sequence in PSQL database

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I am using Postgres 12 with Django 4.0.x and I have a Django App named `Polls` with a model named `Foo` in `polls/models.py`:

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
   ...
```

From the command line, I can inspect my PSQL database:

```
python manage.py dbshell

=> \d
                       List of relations
 Schema |               Name                |   Type   | Owner 
--------+-----------------------------------+----------+-------
 public | auth_group                        | table    | username
...
 public | polls_foo                         | table    | username
 public | polls_foo_id_seq                  | sequence | username
(21 rows)
```

Notice the `polls_foo_id_seq` sequence for my `polls_foo` table.

---

Now I want to refactor and rename the `Foo` class to `Bar`.

But I **also** want to change all database table and sequence names to remove the old name `foo` and change it to `bar`.

So first I change my Python code in `polls/models.py` to:

```py
class Bar(models.Model):
    ...
```

From the command line, I run:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations;
Was the model polls.Foo renamed to Bar? [y/N] y
Migrations for 'polls':
  polls/migrations/0002_rename_foo_bar.py
    - Rename model Foo to Bar

$ python manage.py migrate;
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, polls, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying polls.0002_rename_foo_bar... OK
```

The migration runs smoothly.

Now I want to inspect the change in PSQL, so I run:

```
$ python manage.py dbshell
```

and in the db shell, I list the tables:

```
=> \d
                       List of relations
 Schema |               Name                |   Type   | Owner 
--------+-----------------------------------+----------+-------
 public | auth_group                        | table    | username
 ...
 public | polls_bar                         | table    | username
 public | polls_foo_id_seq                  | sequence | username
(21 rows)
```

So the good news: the table name is successfully changed to `polls_bar`, but the the id sequence for the table is still named `polls_foo_id_seq`. That's bad because it's bound to cause confusion down the line.

How do I also *safely* and *correctly* migrate/change the `polls_foo_id_seq` name to `polls_bar_id_seq`? The solution must be fully compatible with Django, and must be safe for a production migration.